# N-tier web application sample with Ninject?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, ninject

I am trying to learn how to use dependency injection and Ninject. I've been reading blog posts on the topic and Mark Seeman's book "Dependency Injection in .NET". While I have a general understanding of DI, I have troubles understanding how to organize code in a n-tier web application.

Does anyone know of a project sample that I can download, or a blog post to review? Even better if the sample is based on Ninject and MVC3.

Comment: You do realize that the book has tons of sample code to download? No Ninject, though, but since application architecture should be container-agnostic, that ought not to matter :)

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your answer. I certainly didn't expect an answer from the author of the book I mentioned.

I am aware of the code but I still have a hard time figuring things out in relation to how to organize code in layers. I have found your book extremely interesting and well done and it certainly made me question the way I have coded web applications so far. The way I have been working on web applications so far definitely fits your example of Mary's e-commerce application.

Answer (score 4):

NerdDinner is a sample ASP.NET MVC project, and it has been updated to MVC 3: http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/

There are modified versions of the old MVC 2 version that use Ninject and Unity for dependency injection: http://nerddinneraddons.codeplex.com/ The author of those projects provided a different sample application using MVC 3 and Entity Framework 4.1: http://efmvc.codeplex.com/ but used AutoFac rather than Ninject for dependency injection.

Comment: Thank you Martin. I'll take a look at EFMVC.

Answer (score 3):

There's [S#arp Lite](https://github.com/codai/Sharp-Lite), a light version of [S#arp Architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/) recently started by S#arp Architecture's original author.

His introductory blogposts:

- [Introducing S#arp Lite ...S#arp Architecture's pompous little sister](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2011/10/26/s-arp-lite-like-beer-but-better.aspx)
- [S#arp Lite: The Basics](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2011/11/11/s-arp-lite-the-basicss.aspx)

Comment: Argh... another framework to deal with! :)

Thank you for your answer, Christian. I'll take a deeper look at S#arp Lite. Based on what I read in the description it sounds interesting.